# Opening title bar/program icon context menu in a custom location [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, contextmenu, titlebar

I was trying to create an extended title bar in my program, I got the basic functionality, such as the extension from the glass frame, the actual moving of the window on click, but I still don't know where to start when mimicking the context menu that appears when right clicking the Windows title bar.

Of course, I could probably throw down some self-made context menu that looks exactly the same, but that would be quite cheaty, inconsistent, and not native.

Here's the code I am currently using:

```cs
private void Navbar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        while (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }
    }
}

private void Navbar_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
        // open the title bar context menu
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**ALSO,** I didn't try anything YET, because I don't know where to start, and everywhere I looked for, everything was talking about *modifying* the context menu, not even describing how to display it programmatically.

**I even found a Stack Overflow post that asked for almost the same thing, but instead talking about modifying it, which was not what I wanted. One of it's tags were `wpf` but it got closed as a duplicate to a post asking how to do that in WinForms, with another answer talking about WinForms, even though the question had the `wpf` tag.**

Stack Overflow's automatic "*Do any of these posts answer your question?*" tool gave results that were completely unrelated to my question, and brings us back to square one.

Comment: Look at the [WindowChrome.CaptionHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.captionheight?view=windowsdesktop-7.0?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) property.

Comment: @mm8 update: it apparently did work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [WindowChrome.CaptionHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.captionheight?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-7.0?WT.mc_id=DWD-MVP-5001077) property to specify the area at the top of your custom window that enables the system behaviors typically associated with the title bar, such as for example displaying the `ContextMenu`.